# C++Hice un programa pero al momento de correrlo, lee los datos que pido, pero no me carga, no sale error, simplemente se queda trabado

Tags: c++

Soy nuevo en esto de la programación, tengo una tarea de realizar código para factorizar de la forma AX2+BX+C, pero mediante agrupación, lo había realizado en pseint, donde si funcionaba, pero al momento de pasarlo en c++, lee a,b, y c, pero después de leer c, ya no sale nada más...

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath> //Para usar abs
#include <conio.h>
//en este archivo se encuentran definidas las operaciones básicas para leer y escribir datos en patanlla
using namespace std;
int main() //función principal
{

    int a,b,c, bx,D,aa,a11,D11,a1,b1,c1, min, mcddd, mcdd, i, a12, D12 ;
    float x1,x2,x, x11, x12;

    cout <<"Programa para factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c";
    cout <<"Ingrese el termino cuadratico (A) "; cin >> a; // lee a
    cout <<"Ingrese el termino lineal (B)"; cin >> b; // lee b
    cout <<"Ingrese el termino independiente (C)"; cin >> c; // lee c
    
    //Asegurar que los tres valores sean diferentes a 0 para poder factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c
    while (a==0||b==0||c==0){
        cout << "Cantidad no valida para factorizar ax^2+bx+c, intente nuevamente ingresando un valor diferente a 0";
        cout<< "Ingrese el termino cuadratico (A)"; cin >>  a;
        cout << "Ingrese el termino lineal (B)"; cin >> b;
        cout << "Ingrese el termino independiente (C)"; cin >>  c ;
    }
    
    //Valor Absoluto para buscar mínimos sin problema, ejemplo no escoja -45 menor que 30
    a1=abs(a);
    b1=abs(b);
    c1=abs(c);
    
    //En caso de que haya factor común. Se busca el MCD de los tres
        if (a1<b1 && a1<c1) {
            min = a1;
        }
            else if (b1<a1 && b1<c1){
                    min = b1;
            }
            else{
            min = c1;   
            }
            i = 1;
            while (i<=min){
                if (a1 % i==0 && b1 % i==0 && c1 % i==0) {
                mcddd =i;
                }   
            }
            i++; //i=i+1
            
        //Para dividirlo en cada uno y apartar al final el factor común de la factorización
        if (mcddd!=1) {
            a=a/mcddd;
            b=b/mcddd;
            c=c/mcddd;
        }
        
        //Algoritmo para hallar dos números que sumados den un número, y multiplicados otro específico
        //x+y=B, X*y=C*A
        bx= -(c*a);
    
        //Utilizando la fórmula cuadrática, reemplazando el a por un -1, teniendo en cuenta que al reemplazar x+y=b
        //despejada, o sea x=b-y, en x*y=CA, el resultado del término cuadrático siempre será -1
        //La ecuación quedaría -y2+b*y-C*A, por eso en vez de poner c en x se pone bx
        x= (b*b-4*(-1)*bx);
        x1= (-b+sqrt(x))/(2*(-1)); //sqrt gracias a la librería math 
        x2= (-b-sqrt(x))/(2*(-1));
        
        if (x<0) {
        cout << "No se puede factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c, ya que, hay una raíz negativa";
        }
        //Simplificar la expresión
        D=a; //Divisor de toda la expresión, para simplificar, hasta que quede en 1
        aa=a; //De forma
        
        while (D != 1){
            x11=abs(x1);
            a11=abs(a);
            D11=abs(D);
                    
            //Absoluto porque si no asimila los negativos como menores
            if (x11<a11 && x1<D11) {
                min = x11;
            }   
                else if (a11<x11 && a11<D11) {
                    min = a11;
                }
            else{
            min = D11;
            }
            
            i = 1;
            while (i<=min){
                if (fmod(x11,i)==0 && fmod(a11,i)==0 && fmod(D11,i)==0) {
                    mcdd = i;
                }
            i++;
            }
                
            //if se puede va a dividir entre el MCD del grupo, además de dividir D, que sería el numerador de TODA la agrupación
            x1=x1/mcdd;
            a=a/mcdd;
            D=D/mcdd;
            
            //aaa
//Simplificación del segundo grupo
            if (D!=1){
                    
                x12=abs(x2);
                a12=abs(aa);
                D12=abs(D);
               
                if (x12<a12 && x12<D12) {
                    min = x12;
                }   
                    else if (a12<x12 && a12<D12) {                          
                        min = a12;
                    }
                    else{
                        min = D12;
                    }
                
                i = 1;
                while (i<=min) {
                    if (fmod(x12,i)==0 && fmod(a12,i)==0 && fmod(D12,i)==0) {
                        mcdd = i;
                    }
                    i = i+1;                    
                }

                x2=x2/mcdd;
                aa=aa/mcdd;
                D=D/mcdd;
    
                }
        }
        
//Imprimir resultados para las posibles opciones, cuando es mayor, mayor, menor, y combinaciones
//Tiene varios debido a la prueba y error que se realizó, y se identificó que se comportaba diferente
//Dependiendo cuál era mayor (en un caso), a si tenía factor común, y si se podía simplificar
    
    if (mcddd!=1 && a>0 && b>0 && c>0){
        cout << mcddd,"(", a, "x", "+",x1,")", "(", aa, "x", "+",x2,")", "=",0;
    }
        
        else if(mcddd!=1 && a>0 && b<0 && c<0){
            cout << mcddd, "(", a, "x",x1,")", "(", aa, "x", "+",x2,")", "=",0;
        }
            
            else if (mcddd!=1 && a>0 && b<0 && c>0){
                if (a1<b1){
                    cout << mcddd, "(", a, "x",x2,")", "(", aa, "x",x1,")", "=",0;
                }
                    else if (a1>b1){
                            cout << mcddd, "(", a, "x",x1,")", "(", aa, "x",x2,")", "=",0;
                    }
            }
                
//Debido a que depende cual es mayor, cambia el resultado
                        
    else if (mcddd!=1 && a>0 && b>0 && c<0){
        cout << mcddd, "(", aa, "x+",x2,")", "(", a, "x",x1,")", "=",0;
    }       
        else if (D=1 && a>0 && b<0 && c<0) {
                cout << "(", a, "x",x1,")", "(", aa, "x", "+", x2,")", "=",0;
        }
            else if (D=1 && a>0 && b>0 && c>0){
                cout << "(", a, "x", "+",x1,")", "(", aa, "x", "+", x2,")", "=",0;
            }
                else if (D=1 && a>0 && b<0 && c>0){
                    cout << "(", a, "x",x1,")", "(", aa, "x",x2,")", "=",0;
                }
                    else if (a>0 && b>0 && c>0) {
                            cout << "(", a, "x", "+",x1,")", "(", aa, "x", "+",x2,")", "=",0;
                    }
                        else if (a>0 && b<0 && c>0) {
                                cout << "(", a, "x",x2,")", "(", aa, "x",x1,")", "=",0;
                        }
                            else if (a>0 && b<0 && c<0) {
                                    cout << "(", a, "x","+",x2,")", "(", aa, "x",x1,")", "=",0;
                            }
                                else if (a>0 && b>0 && c<0) {
                                        cout << "(", a, "x",x1,")", "(", aa, "x","+",x2,")", "=",0;
                                }
                                else{
                                    cout << "No se puede factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c";
                                }
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: PSeInt tiene una opción para mostrar el código en otros lenguajes de programación. Podrías probarla. Un consejo: dale nombres más descriptivos a tus variables. De seguro no te hubiera gustado que tus padres les pongan a sus hijos: **a**, **b**, **c**, ... Te facilitará entender el código.

Comment: No es necesario que declares todas tus variables en la misma línea. No solo que es engorroso de leer, sino que consumen tiempo y espacio y a veces ni llegan a usarse. Es mejor declararlas justo antes de usarlas, [en el ámbito más pequeño posible](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3773458).

Comment: @Mateo o sea que el código tiene problema por lo largo?

Comment: La extensión del código no importa demasiado. Pero tampoco es para poner un código de más de 1000 líneas o un proyecto entero. Sí te indique una malas prácticas.

Answer (score 3):

Hay un par de detalles:

1. La línea `i++; //i=i+1` debe estar dentro del ciclo while
2. Tienes que reemplazar las comas por << después de usar cout

Envío un código que funciona.

Saludos.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>    //Para usar abs
#include <conio.h>
    //en este archivo se encuentran definidas las operaciones básicas para leer y escribir datos en patanlla
using namespace std;
int main()  //función principal
{

    int a, b, c, bx, D, aa, a11, D11, a1, b1, c1, min, mcddd, mcdd, i, a12, D12;
    float x1, x2, x, x11, x12;

    cout << "Programa para factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c";
    cout << "Ingrese el termino cuadratico (A) ";
    cin >> a;   // lee a
    cout << "Ingrese el termino lineal (B)";
    cin >> b;   // lee b
    cout << "Ingrese el termino independiente (C)";
    cin >> c;   // lee c

    //Asegurar que los tres valores sean diferentes a 0 para poder factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c
    while (a == 0 || b == 0 || c == 0)
    {
        cout << "Cantidad no valida para factorizar ax^2+bx+c, intente nuevamente ingresando un valor diferente a 0";
        cout << "Ingrese el termino cuadratico (A)";
        cin >> a;
        cout << "Ingrese el termino lineal (B)";
        cin >> b;
        cout << "Ingrese el termino independiente (C)";
        cin >> c;
    }

    //Valor Absoluto para buscar mínimos sin problema, ejemplo no escoja -45 menor que 30
    a1 = abs(a);
    b1 = abs(b);
    c1 = abs(c);

    //En caso de que haya factor común. Se busca el MCD de los tres
    if (a1 < b1 && a1 < c1)
    {
        min = a1;
    }
    else if (b1 < a1 && b1 < c1)
    {
        min = b1;
    }
    else
    {
        min = c1;
    }
    i = 1;
    while (i <= min)
    {
        if (a1 % i == 0 && b1 % i == 0 && c1 % i == 0)
        {
            mcddd = i;
        }
        i++;    //i=i+1
    }

    //Para dividirlo en cada uno y apartar al final el factor común de la factorización
    if (mcddd != 1)
    {
        a = a / mcddd;
        b = b / mcddd;
        c = c / mcddd;
    }

    //Algoritmo para hallar dos números que sumados den un número, y multiplicados otro específico
    //x+y=B, X *y =C*A
    bx = -(c *a);

    //Utilizando la fórmula cuadrática, reemplazando el a por un -1, teniendo en cuenta que al reemplazar x+y=b
    //despejada, o sea x=b-y, en x *y =CA, el resultado del término cuadrático siempre será -1
    //La ecuación quedaría -y2+b*y-C*A, por eso en vez de poner c en x se pone bx
    x = (b *b - 4 *(-1) *bx);
    x1 = (-b + sqrt(x)) / (2 *(-1));    //sqrt gracias a la librería math 
    x2 = (-b - sqrt(x)) / (2 *(-1));

    if (x < 0)
    {
        cout << "No se puede factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c, ya que, hay una raíz negativa";
    }
    //Simplificar la expresión
    D = a;  //Divisor de toda la expresión, para simplificar, hasta que quede en 1
    aa = a; //De forma

    while (D != 1)
    {
        x11 = abs(x1);
        a11 = abs(a);
        D11 = abs(D);

        //Absoluto porque si no asimila los negativos como menores
        if (x11 < a11 && x1 < D11)
        {
            min = x11;
        }
        else if (a11 < x11 && a11 < D11)
        {
            min = a11;
        }
        else
        {
            min = D11;
        }

        i = 1;
        while (i <= min)
        {
            if (fmod(x11, i) == 0 && fmod(a11, i) == 0 && fmod(D11, i) == 0)
            {
                mcdd = i;
            }
            i++;
        }

        //if se puede va a dividir entre el MCD del grupo, además de dividir D, que sería el numerador de TODA la agrupación
        x1 = x1 / mcdd;
        a = a / mcdd;
        D = D / mcdd;

        //aaa
        //Simplificación del segundo grupo
        if (D != 1)
        {

            x12 = abs(x2);
            a12 = abs(aa);
            D12 = abs(D);

            if (x12 < a12 && x12 < D12)
            {
                min = x12;
            }
            else if (a12 < x12 && a12 < D12)
            {
                min = a12;
            }
            else
            {
                min = D12;
            }

            i = 1;
            while (i <= min)
            {
                if (fmod(x12, i) == 0 && fmod(a12, i) == 0 && fmod(D12, i) == 0)
                {
                    mcdd = i;
                }
                i = i + 1;
            }

            x2 = x2 / mcdd;
            aa = aa / mcdd;
            D = D / mcdd;
        }
    }
    //Imprimir resultados para las posibles opciones << cuando es mayor << mayor << menor << y combinaciones
    //Tiene varios debido a la prueba y error que se realizó << y se identificó que se comportaba diferente
    //Dependiendo cuál era mayor (en un caso) << a si tenía factor común << y si se podía simplificar

    if (mcddd != 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0)
    {
        cout << mcddd << "(" << a << "x" << "+" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << "+" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (mcddd != 1 && a > 0 && b < 0 && c < 0)
    {
        cout << mcddd << "(" << a << "x" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << "+" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (mcddd != 1 && a > 0 && b < 0 && c > 0)
    {
        if (a1 < b1)
        {
            cout << mcddd << "(" << a << "x" << x2 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << x1 << ")" << "=" << 0;
        }
        else if (a1 > b1)
        {
            cout << mcddd << "(" << a << "x" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
        }
    }

    //Debido a que depende cual es mayor << cambia el resultado
    else if (mcddd != 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c < 0)
    {
        cout << mcddd << "(" << aa << "x+" << x2 << ")" << "(" << a << "x" << x1 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (D = 1 && a > 0 && b < 0 && c < 0)
    {
        cout << "(" << a << "x" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << "+" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (D = 1 && a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0)
    {
        cout << "(" << a << "x" << "+" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << "+" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (D = 1 && a > 0 && b < 0 && c > 0)
    {
        cout << "(" << a << "x" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (a > 0 && b > 0 && c > 0)
    {
        cout << "(" << a << "x" << "+" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << "+" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (a > 0 && b < 0 && c > 0)
    {
        cout << "(" << a << "x" << x2 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << x1 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (a > 0 && b < 0 && c < 0)
    {
        cout << "(" << a << "x" << "+" << x2 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << x1 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else if (a > 0 && b > 0 && c < 0)
    {
        cout << "(" << a << "x" << x1 << ")" << "(" << aa << "x" << "+" << x2 << ")" << "=" << 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "No se puede factorizar de la forma ax^2+bx+c";
    }
    getch();
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, si funcionó :D

Comment: @AndresAcevedo si esta respuesta soluciona tu problema, por favor, márcala como solución. Gracias